# Is it possible to write a php / ajax script that monitors a table for row changes?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

My question is as follows,

I need to write a script that monitors a database table for changes and then when an update to the table happens that information gets sent to a web service to be sent to a clients database. Our database is a MySQL database.

A trigger isn't a good solution because our database is hosted on amazon web services and the only available methods are only useable if you have the SUPER privilege.

The only solutions i have been able to find are 1. Websockets or 2. longpolling.

I'm really not sure the best possible way to go about this.. can anyone point me in the right direction on what i should be searching for?

Comment: If you're using Amazon, why not use [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) to schedule things like this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. but either you use server push (e.g. websockets), or client pull (e.g. polling).

Comment: thank you for your answers.

Comment: Can you add logic to the code that inserts/updates/deletes the table rows? So instead of polling, or websockets, just execute the logic you need at the point where the data gets inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: That is normally the way that i wanted to go. My boss wants it to go into the database first then get sent out. If all else fails though that is the way i am going to go about it